# Multi:true update collection lock

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When a collection is updated using `multi:true`, is there a lock on the entire collection or will it be an individual document level lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire collection is only locked if the [`$isolated`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/isolated/#isolated) operator is used with a `multi:true` update. Otherwise, each affected document is updated atomically, but other write activity may interleave between document updates.

See [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) on the topic for the full details.